# Creating a Hash with keys from an array and empty arrays as the values

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have the array tags, which consists of a number of Strings that I need to use to create a new Hash (content) where each value is an empty array. I currently have     `Hash[*tags.map {|k| [k, nil]}.flatten]`, but this returns:

```
{
  "tag1" => nil,
  "tag2" => nil,
  "tag3" => nil
}
```

when I want it to be

```
{
  "tag1" => [],
  "tag2" => [],
  "tag3" => []
}
```

sorry this is kind of a dumb question, but I've googled around and can't find the answer. Thank you!

Comment: Note: I have tried replacing nil with [ ] in Hash[*tags.map {|k| [k, nil]}.flatten], that doesn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [flatten](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-flatten), map `[]` instead of `nil` like you tried, then use `flatten(1)`. That eliminates only the first layer of array, so you get `['tag1', [], ...]` to pass to `Hash[]`.

```
> tags = %w[tag1 tag2 tag3]
 => ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
> tags.map {|k| [k, []]}.flatten
 => ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
> tags.map {|k| [k, []]}.flatten(1)
 => ["tag1", [], "tag2", [], "tag3", []]
> Hash[*tags.map {|k| [k, []]}.flatten(1)]
 => {"tag1"=>[], "tag2"=>[], "tag3"=>[]}
```

You can also avoid `flatten` altogether if you drop the splat (`*`) from `Hash[]`, since [::[]](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) also accepts a list of pairs.

```
> tags.map {|k| [k, []]}
 => [["tag1", []], ["tag2", []], ["tag3", []]]
> Hash[tags.map {|k| [k, []]}]
 => {"tag1"=>[], "tag2"=>[], "tag3"=>[]}
```

Comment: You can also write `Hash[*tags.flat_map { |k| [k, []]}]`.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby's Array supports (Cartesian) product so you can take advantage of this, without need of extra logic built inside block(s):

```
> tags.product([[]]).to_h
=> {"tag1"=>[], "tag2"=>[], "tag3"=>[]}
```

Simple.

Comment: Nice. Very nice! (I noticed the mindmeld. btw, who's "Rachel"?)

Comment: I feel funny pasting a comment, but since this is the same solution...problem is the [same Array object gets assigned](https://gist.github.com/kristjan/87be1352953490e4b9b5) to all three values, which is probably undesirable.

Comment: David, I was going to say "This is completely wrong. What were you thinking??", but realized that wouldn't make much sense now that I've deleted my identical answer, so I won't say that. @Kristján, you were right in doing so. Good catch.

Comment: I'm sort of disappointed I noticed, it was a really slick solution otherwise.  Now I'm going to be looking for ways to use `product` all week :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Hash.html#method-c-new) `Hash.new` accepts a block which you can use to provide a default value each time a new key, not belonging to the Hash, is accessed. 
So you can use this

```
tags = %w(tag1 tag2 tag3)
h = Hash.new{ |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
tags.each{ |tag| h[tag] }
# h == {"tag1"=>[], "tag2"=>[], "tag3"=>[]}
h['tag4']
# h == {"tag1"=>[], "tag2"=>[], "tag3"=>[], "tag4"=>[]}
```

Answer (score 0):

One more way:

```
tags = %w|tag1 tag2 tag3|

Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }.tap { |h| h.values_at(*tags) }
  #=> {"tag1"=>[], "tag2"=>[], "tag3"=>[]}
```